# How to make a custom module in Mobile OpenERP (android)?

Tags: java, android, postgresql, odoo

OpenERP in python is very easy to understand and work with. But in Android, it seems a little difficult. I'm studying mobile openERP framework to be able to CRUD with server database(postgreSQL). I don't know how to create a module in it. Any idea....?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly Have a look at : http://mobile.openerp.co.in/ 
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: This site is down.  please provide another site that have a documentation

Comment: This domain(**openerp.co.in**) name expired on Apr 12 2015 09:56:41:000AM 
Click here to renew it.

Answer (score 1):

There are already official app.

### [OpenERP Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.openerp)

or you can develop your own.

### [OpenERP Mobile Framework Doc](http://mobile.openerp.co.in/)

Thanks